# how to fix xaxis label on Flot js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, flot

I'm using 'Categories' mode to display labels. It works fine with small number of datas on graph but when I have more than 100 of datas there is no way to see the labels. Is there any solution for flot js ?

[image]

Graph with more datas will be like :

[image]

Below is the options I'm using to display the graph :

```
var stackOptionSeries = { stack: true, bars:  { show: true,  barWidth: 0.4, align: 'center',lineWidth: 1.5, fillColor: { colors: [ { opacity: 0.9 }, { opacity: 0.8 } ] }  } };

    var options = {
    grid:{ hoverable: true,
           clickable: true,
           autoHighlight:true,
           backgroundColor: 'white',
           borderWidth:1,
           borderColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
           tickColor:'#FAFAFA'},
    series: stackOptionSeries,
    legend: {
      show: true,
      position: "ne",
      noColumns: 1
    },
    xaxis: {
      mode: "categories",
      tickLength: 0,
      panRange: [-0.2, maxXaxisRange+0.2]
    },
    yaxes:  [{ min: 0,ticks:7, panRange: [0,null], zoomRange: false }, {
      position: "right",
      autoscaleMargin: 1,
      ticks:4,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      panRange: [0,null],
      zoomRange: false
    }],
    pan: {
        interactive: true,
        frameRate: 80
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      content: "%y %s, %x", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
      shifts: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10
      },
      defaultTheme: false
    } 
  };
```

Comment: The only purpose of categories mode is to allow text labels.  If you don't intend for the labels to be shown, then why are you using it?  In your case, where x-axis values appear to correspond to dates, why aren't you using a time-mode axis instead?

Answer (score 1):

Hei
How about using angled labels? then the labels should not show on top of each other.

```
 xaxis: {
            labelAngle: 45}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manishsp2008/vNSD8/

Hope it helps